# iOS/Swift : Automatically Pair With Bluetooth Classic Device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, external-accessory, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are building a custom Bluetooth device that supports both Bluetooth Classic for Handsfree as well as Bluetooth LE for other features. I am able to connect and communicate with the device via Bluetooth LE however, right now the user must manually pair with the device from Settings in order for the handsfree stuff to work. Like the Apple Watch, is it possible to automatically pair with the device via Bluetooth Classic when the device is selected from the Bluetooth LE list of available devices?

Basically, here is how we want it to work.

1. User launches application for the first time.
2. User is redirected to registration screen and registers their phone with our environment.
3. User is taken to the applications Dashboard and then clicks the applications Settings button.
4. In Settings, the user clicks Bluetooth Peripherals and is taken to a screen with a list of the BLE devices in range.

Here is where the new magic needs to happen:

5. User chooses BLE device, the devices is discovered and connected to via BLE.
6. After the devices characteristics have been discovered, the application should pair with the device via Bluetooth Classic for the handsfree stuff to work such as the microphone and speaker.

Any help is appreciated.

I have looked into the External Accessory framework however, I was unable to get it to even work properly. The application kept failing telling me "init" was not available or something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We're trying to do the same thing and it looks like you can only pair a hands-free device working via HFP profile if leaving your app, going to Bluetooth settings in Settings.app and tapping the device there. From the app it's absolutely impossible. All the hands-free vendors I checked recently (Jabra, Parrot, etc.) do it this way.

The only thing I can think about would be pair via BLE, send the iPhone name to your hands-free accessory via BLE open Bluetooth settings screen in the Settings.app and wait for the accessory to discover the iPhone and connect to it from its side. This will save your user a tap, but he will still have to open the Settings.app (manually, bloody hell, not even via a system alert).

ExternalAccessory.framework is used to connect with devices registered in MFi program. It has absolutely nothing to do with hands-free devices working with HFP profile.